# Ubuntu clock jumps

Tags: 22.04, python, time, clock

I've noticed that since the last update of the Ubuntu kernel (specs are below) the OS clock randomly jumps seconds.

I'm using Python 3.10.12 and **Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS 6.2.0-26-GENERIC**

I've noticed because making it run a simple Python app, I've noticed the timestamp on the print statements are not in chronological order.

Opening the clock application also shows that seconds run, sometimes faster, sometimes slower, and sometimes they jump from a certain number to another.

Below an example of print of the console and the timestamp of my Django app

```
[2023-08-28 17:11:00,078: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:01,190: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:02,378: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:03,462: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:04,630: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:05,758: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:07,122: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:08,350: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:09,606: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:10,966: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:10:55,717: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:10:56,938: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:10:58,294: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:10:59,514: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:00,842: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:02,494: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:04,098: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:05,798: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:09,506: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:10,542: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:11,666: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:12,803: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:14,043: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:15,147: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:16,251: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:17,351: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:18,383: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:19,427: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:20,495: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:21,579: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:22,691: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:23,847: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:24,987: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:26,151: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:11,857: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:12,969: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:14,117: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:15,197: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:16,281: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:17,489: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:18,650: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:19,774: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:20,850: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
```

Comment: Hardware problem ? What time-sync tool are you using (ntp, systemd) ?

Comment: @Marco timedatectl is active as well as NTP and system clock synchronized